# Circuit Protection

Tags: protection

I want something for my power that acts like a diode, but without the voltage drop, to protect the circuit from damage if the batteries are connected the wrong way. Is this even possible?

Comment: I like Microsoft's mind-blowing invention, [here](http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/mouseandkeyboard/licensing/instaloadoverview.mspx).

Comment: @tyblu, Interesting how it has been invented already: US Patent 5431575.

Comment: @Thomas O, Must have either sold his soul to MS or conveniently *disappeared*.

Comment: @tyblu Either that, or Microsoft didn't do a thorough check on possible prior art - OR - Microsoft knows it's prior art, but knows the small company or individual doesn't stand a chance against their small army of lawyers.

Comment: @tyblu are you sure you haven't sold your soul to MS since this is the second time you have linked it? :-) @ThomasO That patent is for the mechanical aspects of the holder and not the electronics. I am sure MS is capable of designing a different holder or licensing it.

Comment: @kellenjb, InstaLoad is entirely mechanical (with virtually the same design verbatim), there are no electronic parts in it. Microsoft have patented page up and page down already. So it wouldn't surprise me.

Comment: @ThomasO I am not sure if I should think you are agreeing with me or disagreeing with me.

Comment: @thomasO, @kellenjb, @tyblu. Holding a patent does not give validity. It is designed to require a court case to uphold it before it is considered "valid". Researching prior art increases your fine if they turn down your patent for prior art. The idea being that you should have seen it. In reality it is very very hard to find prior art and much easier to file a patent.

Comment: @kellenjb, I am disagreeing with "electronic", as it is the same as calling a battery holder "electronic".

Comment: @ThomasO I said it's not electronic, then you said it's not electronic, then you said you are disagreeing with me. I am rather confused.

Comment: @kellenjb, I don't think I ever said it was elctronic, I may have misread you. "That patent is for the mechanical aspects of the holder and not the electronics" would seem to indicate there are some electronics in it, but I may have misunderstood.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Put the diode across the supply connections so that it is non-conducting, with a fuse ahead of it. The diode will conduct if the supply is reversed, and blow the fuse. There won't be any voltage drop.

[image]

Comment: how does this protect the circuit? it just tells me that i've plugged it in the wrong way.

Comment: @Dean, Good point. Skip the fuse and put a diode that can handle a s/c.

Comment: Why doesn't it protect the circuit?

Comment: After the fuse blows, the battery will still be in backwards and the diode disconnected.

Comment: @tyblu The fuse is in series with the battery line and the diode is in reverse across the supply. It will work. I think you're thinking of putting the fuse in series with the diode and the load across the battery, which wouldn't serve any purpose. I have done this before and it works, but it's obviously annoying to have to replace fuses.

Comment: That is indeed what I'm thinking. Thanks for clearing that up!

Comment: @Leon Heller I hope you don't mind, I added a picture since it seemed some people weren't fully clear what was happening. Feel free to remove or replace if you aren't happy with it.

Comment: Since reversing the power supply won't damage the circuit, Leon's solution does indeed protect it. It may not work with reversed power supply, but it won't be damaged.

Comment: I believe this would be called a crowbar.

Comment: You could use a Resettable Fuse (aka PTC or polyfuse), then no need to replace blown fuses. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resettable_fuse

Answer (score 10):

A MOSFET can be used to protect a circuit with a low voltage drop.  See the following for more information:

[Reverse Battery Protection with Hexfets doubles Battery Life](http://www.irf.com/technical-info/designtp/dt94-8.pdf)

[Advanced Power Switching and Polarity Protection for Effects](http://www.geofex.com/Article_Folders/mosswitch/mosswitch.htm)

Comment: Careful with these circuits though: if you attempt to use a reverse supply voltage over the maximum voltage of the MOSFET gate (usually ±20V) it won't be pretty.

Comment: If you need to survive larger voltages, you can either add a resistor divider or zener.

Answer (score 5):

You might try what's called a Schottky diode. A normal diode has a drop of around 0.6 V, but Schottky's are around 0.2 V. At very low currents, the drop can be even lower.

Comment: I would suggest this as a comment on Leon's post.

Comment: I should have been more clear-- I'm suggesting using a Schottky diode in series with the battery, not in parallel. I think that's different from what Leon is suggesting. (I think what Leon suggests is pretty good, but blowing fuses annoys some people.)

Comment: I thought that might be what you meant. I Would suggest editing that into your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am planning to use the [LTC4365](http://www.linear.com/pc/productDetail.jsp?navId=H0,C1,C1003,C1142,C1029,P131997), but that's overkill, because it has overvoltage and undervoltage protection built in (which I have a use for because it may be used in an automotive environment, but you might not.)

Comment: Linear has many "ideal diode" type things IIRC.

Comment: @XTL, Indeed, although some of them are overkill for this application.